# Windows Powershell v4.0 confirms current hour is 08, but $hour > 1 evaluates to "False"

Tags: powershell, time, hour

The code below is a PowerShell script that does not execute when it is supposed to.  I added some echoes to test each conditional statement and as you can see, it does not recognize that the hour is 8 (or 08) inside the conditional statement for some reason.  Does anyone know why?

```
$hour = get-date -UFormat %H
$min = get-date -UFormat %M

If ( ($hour -eq 7 -and $min -gt 45) -or ($hour -eq 8 -and $min -lt 55) ) {
start ["filename"]}

echo $hour                     \\returns "08"
echo ($hour -gt .999)           \\returns "True"
echo ($hour -gt 1)               \\returns "False" 
echo ($hour -gt 02)               \\returns "False"

EXIT
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You assign $hour and $min a string format and compare it with a double; when comparing values of different type PowerShell converts the RHS to the type of the LHS so all your above results are string based and insofar correct.

Comment: Thanks to all for your help, very simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$hour` variable contains a string, not a number. You can force it to a number by changing

```
$hour = get-date -UFormat %H
$min = get-date -UFormat %M
```

to

```
[int]$hour = get-date -UFormat %H
[int]$min = get-date -UFormat %M
```

or preferably by not casting anything and using the functions the `[DateTime]` object provides

```
$hour = (get-date).Hour
$min = (get-date).Minute
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are comparing a string to an integer.

Here an example and solution

```
PS H:\> get-date -UFormat %H
09

PS H:\> (get-date -UFormat %H).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------            
True     True     String                                   System.Object       



PS H:\> (get-date -UFormat %H) > 1

PS H:\> ([int]( get-date -UFormat %H))
9

PS H:\> ([int]( get-date -UFormat %H)).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------            
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType    



PS H:\> ([int]( get-date -UFormat %H)) -gt 1
True
```

Even better (Thanks LotPings)

```
PS H:\> ((Get-Date).Hour).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------            
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType    



PS H:\> (Get-Date).Hour -gt 1
True
```

Comment: `$hour = (Get-Date).Hour`